# Inconsistent getTimezoneOffset results

Tags: javascript, datetime

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) seems to suggest getTimezoneOffset() always returns the offset of the current locale, irregardless of the date object. But I'm getting inconsistent results that I can't understand.

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()                             // -120
new Date("2015-03-10T15:48:05+01:00").getTimezoneOffset()  // -60
new Date("2015-03-10T15:48:05-04:00").getTimezoneOffset()  // -60
```

Also, is there a better way to get the timezone off a datetime string (maybe with moment.js)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getTimezoneOffset` returns the offset for *the specific moment in time* represented by the `Date` object it is called on, using the time zone setting of the computer that it executing the code.

Since many time zones change their offset for [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info), it is perfectly normal for the value to differ for different dates and times.  When you call it on `new Date()`, you're getting the *current* offset.

The value returned from `getTimezoneOffset` is in terms of minutes *west* of UTC, as compared to the more common offsets returned in `[+/-]HH:mm` format, which are *east* of UTC.  Therefore, the time zone you gave alternates between UTC+1, and UTC+2.  My guess is the computer that gave this output was in one of the zones that uses Central European Time - though it could be one of several others.

Also, when you pass in an offset as part of an ISO8601 formatted string, that offset is indeed taken into account - but only during parsing.  The offset is applied, and the `Date` object holds on to the UTC timestamp internally.  It then forgets anything about the offset you supplied.   On output, some of the functions will explicitly use UTC, but most of them will convert to the local time zone before emitting their result.

You also asked about how to get the offset of a datetime string using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  Yes, that is quite simple:

```
// Create a moment object.
// Use the parseZone function to retain the zone provided.
var m = moment.parseZone('2015-03-10T15:48:05-04:00');

// get the offset in minutes EAST of UTC (opposite of getTimezoneOffset)
var offset = m.utcOffset(); // -240

// alternatively, get it as a string in [+/-]HH:mm format
var offsetString = m.format("Z");  // "-04:00"
```

Comment: For me, if I create different date objects with different timezones, the offset is ALWAYS the offset for MY TIMEZONE. As it is explained here (check code example): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Answer (score 2):

It's because of [Daylight Savings Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). For your timezone, on June 11th it is in UTC+2 and on March 10th it's in UTC+1:

```
// when in DST (since it's June)
new Date("2015-06-11T00:00:00Z").getTimezoneOffset();       // -120
// when not in DST
new Date("2015-03-10T15:48:05+01:00").getTimezoneOffset();  // -60
```

For me, since I'm in the Eastern Time Zone, the following will happen:

```
// when in EST
new Date("2015-03-01T00:00:00Z").getTimezoneOffset();       // 300
// when in EDT
new Date("2015-06-01T00:00:00Z").getTimezoneOffset();       // 240
```

Comment: For me, if I create different date objects with different timezones (as in your examples), the offset is ALWAYS the offset for MY TIMEZONE. As it is explained here (check code example): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset